# Python (2.7.8) : Phonebook, Multiple keys with the same value (Alias)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Phonebook:

      def __init__(self):
          self.bok={('eddie','ed'): '1234',('peter','pete'): '4321'}

      def add(self, name, number):
          if name in self.bok.keys():                     
             print "The name does already exist."
          else:
             self.bok[name] = number                      
             print self.bok

      def lookup(self, name):
          for item in self.bok.keys():
              if name in item:
                 print "Name :", name
                 print "Telephone number: ", self.bok[item]

      def alias(self, name, nick):
          self.bok[name, nick] = self.bok[name]
          del self.bok[name]

      def change(self, name, number):
          for item in self.bok.keys():
              if name in item:
                 print "test"
```

So, what I would like to do is add "Alias" to a chosen name like:

> Alias eddie ed (Adds the alias "ed" to the name "eddie")

But the problem here is that it becomes a Tuple in the dictionary after I've done that so I can't add more Alias'es to the same name with the current function because it only works for Dictionary and not Tuples, like:

> Alias ed eddinator (Adds the alias "eddinator" to the name "ed" wich is connected to eddie) ==> Gives me error.

And then the same problems appears for Change.
Change = The alias'es should always have the same number as the "head" name so if I change eddie's number to 9876 then ed and eddinator should also have it. (Multiple keys with same value)

The lookup function is working.
I'm not really sure this is the easiest way but its currently the only way I've found so far!

Comment: So what should happen when you have multiple `John`s in the phone book?

Comment: Well i guess you shouldn't be able to put the alias-name to someone else "head"-name, like you can't do like this ('eddie','peter'): '1234',('peter','pete'): '4321'} because peter is already in use

Comment: In that case, your phone book will be broken, as there are people who share names in the real world... unless that's not something that you want to address

Comment: I'm allowed to make names unique so it's only allowed to have one of the same name and ALL numbers NEEDS to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the aliases point to the head names, and the have the head names point to the phone number:

```
class Phonebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bok = {'eddie': 1234,
                    'ed': 'eddie',
                    'peter': 4321, 
                    'pete': 'peter'}


    def add(self, name, number):
        if name in self.bok.keys():                     
            print "The name does already exist."
        else:
            self.bok[name] = int(number)
            print self.bok


    def lookup(self, name):
        val = self.bok[name]
        while isinstance(val, str):
            val = self.bok[val]

        print "Name :", name
        print "Telephone number: ", val


    def alias(self, name, nick):
        if nick in self.bok:
            print 'that alias already exists'
            return
        self.bok[nick] = name


    def change(self, name, number):
        while isinstance(self.bok[name], str):
            name = self.bok[name]
        self.bok[name] = int(number)
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\test\Downloads\phonebook2.py", line 23, in lookup
    val = self.bok[val]
KeyError: '5555'

Comment: Would you like the whole code so you can view it all?

Comment: But how do i make it so i can change the number of alias but the "main-name" also gets the number? vice-versa

Comment: @Widdin: there! that should do it!

Comment: But it doesnt really work if i add an alias on the alias x), then if i change the 2nd alias the 3rd alias will have the number <insert 1st name> instead

Comment: @Widdin: I don't think I get that. Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3573         If you look at the last row "fetgang" gets the number "simon"

Comment: Fantastic! there's the code. Now what is the observed behavior, and what is the expected behavior? and how do they differ from each other?

Comment: Well "fetgang" is supposed to have the same number as "Widdin" and "Simon" all the time, if i change "fetgang"'s number then widdin and simon is supposed to have it also, vice versa. Change widdin then simon and fetgang also has it.

Comment: Check out the edit. That should fix the observed behavior

Comment: Works perfect now! Thank you very much :D