# Save/load function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, save, load

I have to create a save function and a load function that saves a dictionary in the format of:

```
123;Kalle;
123;Maria;
321;Anna;
321;Olle;
```

My dictionary is supposed to look like a phonebook, with the key being the name and the value is the phonenumber:

```
telebook = {"jacob":"8472923777", "nisse":"092563243"}
```

How can I write a function that saves my phonebook in the format mentioned? It should look like this:

```
8472923777;jacob;
```

This is my current code:

```
def save(lista, telebook): 
import pickle 
filename = lista[1] 
f = open(filename, "w") 
pickle.dump(telebook, f) 
f.close() 
print telebook 


def load(lista, telebook): 
import pickle 
try: 
    filename = lista[1] 
    f = open(filename, "r") 
    telebook_1 = pickle.load( f ) 
    telebook.clear() 
    telebook.update(telebook_1) 
    f.close() 
    print telebook 
except:
    print "This file doesn't exist"
```

EDIT:

My save function was easier than I thought, managed to solve it on my own. Not sure how to get the load function to work though.

```
book = raw_input("telebook> ").lower()
lista = book.split() 

def save(lista, telebook): 
   filename = lista[1] 
   f = open(filename, "w") 
   for name, num in telebook.items():
       f.write(num+";"+name+";"+"\n")
   f.close() 
   print telebook
```

My load is the same as before but obviously I can't use that one anymore.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Show your attempt and tell us where you're stuck

Comment: we dont write code for you.... we help you with "YOUR CODE"

Comment: Sorry, will edit with current code.

Comment: why are you using `pickle`? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Have you considered talking to [your classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33151799/198633)?

Comment: Huh, didn't know I had people from my class here, couldn't find it when I searched before. Embarrassing...

Comment: Also, I think this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33160122/198633)

Comment: Well, apparently I suck at searching...Thanks for finding it, should I delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(telebok, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for name,num in telebok.items():
            outfile.write("{};{};\n".format(num, name))
```

And to get it back:

```
import csv
def load(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        telebok = dict((v,k) for v,k,_ in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'))
    return telebok
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I used the help you provided for another person with a similar exercise, without importing csv.